# Given clang uses Itanium C++ ABI can I link C++ libraries with different compiler flags?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, abi

Am I allowed to link C++ binaries compiled using different versions of clang? Am I allowed to link C++ binaries compiled using different compiler flags? Is name mangling an issue given the standard-ish ABI?

Comment: There is no universal answer here. It depends on the compiler flags. Usually you can compile different modules with different flags. However to know the definitive answer to this question you need to understand what these different flags do and how they work, and based on that figure out whether this will work without any unwanted surprises. Same with different compiler versions. You will need to check your compiler's documentation to determine whether the different versions are compatible, in terms of code.